# How to avoid additional whitespaces in loggerfile, caused by indentions

Tags: python, logging, coding-style, pep8

today i applied the `PEP 8` coding convention on my project. Therefore i splitted my `logger.debug` to avoid `E501 line to long`. This is what i have now:

```
def find_window():
    ...
    logger.debug("Returning a List of Window handles\
                with specified Windowtitle: {}".format(title))
```

So far, so good, but the bad news is, this is what i get in my loggerfile:

`06/25/2015 02:07:20 PM - DEBUG - libs.Window on 104 : Returning a List of Window handles                with specified Windowtitle: desktop: notepad`

There are additional whitespaces after the word handles. I know if i do something like this:

```
def find_window():
    ...
    logger.debug("Returning a List of Window handles \
with specified Windowtitle: {}".format(title))
```

This would work, but it looks stupid and even more if u have more indentions.
How do i avoid this extra whitespaces in my loggerfile?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
logger.debug((
              "Returning a list of Window handles"
              "with specified Windowtitle: {}"
             ).format(title))
```

Answer (score 1):

This can be an alternative way

```
import re
logger.debug(re.sub('\s+', ' ', "Returning a List of Window handles\
                                 with specified Windowtitle: {}".format(title)))
```